# PHP/JS Credit Card brand echo in Session

Tags: javascript, php

I want print out the Credit card Brand from an Input field and/or save it to an PHP Session if its Possible. Should I do it on same page or on next page?

For example , the User enters an number starting with `"40"` in the input field = `VISA`

Is it Possible using if conditions?

```
<span class="payment-errors required"></span> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $cardinput = $('#checkout_card_number');
    $('#checkout_card_number').validateCreditCard(function(result)
    {       
        //console.log(result);
        if (result.card_type != null)
        {               
            switch (result.card_type.name)
            {
                case "visa":
                    $cardinput.css('background-position', '3px -34px');
                    $cardinput.addClass('card_visa');
                    break;


                case "visa_electron":
                    $cardinput.css('background-position', '3px -72px');
                    $cardinput.addClass('card_visa_electron');
                    break;

                case "mastercard":
                    $cardinput.css('background-position', '3px -110px');
                    $cardinput.addClass('card_mastercard');
                    break;

                case "maestro":
                    $cardinput.css('background-position', '3px -148px');
                    $cardinput.addClass('card_maestro');
                    break;

                case "discover":
                    $cardinput.css('background-position', '3px -186px');
                    $cardinput.addClass('card_discover');
                    break;

                case "amex":
                    $cardinput.css('background-position', '3px -223px');
                    $cardinput.addClass('card_amex');
                    break;

                default:
                    $cardinput.css('background-position', '3px 3px');
                    break;                  
            }
        } else {
            $cardinput.css('background-position', '3px 3px');
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Any one an Idea?

Comment: if you know which numbers correspond to which card brand then yes of course you can use an if statement, or a switch statement. Where you do that depends on your application's requirements, it's really up to you.